# How to read the external html file as a DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The data.html file is simple such as below.

```
<table id="test">
<tr>
<td>f1</td>
<td>f2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>y</td>
<td>70</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I can read it with FileReader.

```js
  
function readAsText(){  
    var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];  
    var reader = new FileReader();  
    reader.readAsText(file);  
    reader.onload=function(){  
        _table=this.result;
        alert(_table);  
    }  
}
```

```html
<p>  
    <label>to select a file</label>  
    <input type="file" id="file" />  
    <input type="button" value="read as text" onclick="readAsText()" />  
</p>
```

[image]
[image]
The data.html can be read as a text file not DOM tree,how to read it as a dom tree?
How to get the rows number of data.html file?
`_table.rows.length` can not get the rows number because the _table is not a dom tree,can i change it into a dom tree to operate?

```
        _table=this.result;
        alert(_table.rows.length);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) API does just that :

```js
var markup = '<table id="test">'+
'<tr>'+
'<td>f1</td>'+
'<td>f2</td>'+
'</tr>'+
'<tr>'+
'<td>y</td>'+
'<td>70</td>'+
'</tr>'+
'</table>';

var parsedDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(markup, 'text/html');
console.log('number of rows:', parsedDoc.getElementById('test').rows.length)

console.log('textContent of the fourth td:',parsedDoc.querySelectorAll('td')[3].textContent);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `jquery load` method.

```
$('#someDivId').load('some-file.html');
```

[jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: from a user file, you'll need to first use a FileReader to encode it to a dataURI